# Why does opening a file take so long in python mode?

Tags: python, find-file

Opening a small python file, with <10 buffers open, takes a long time. [Here's a gist of the profile](https://gist.github.com/vlad17/afb549b085f280ecbc503389ccf967ae) of trying to open this file (giving up with `C-g` after 2 minutes).

Deactivating ido-mode tells more or less the same story. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/vlad17/dfb8eccc6f0a57b536a41e3c035deedc) for details.

Messages during the opening of the file:

```
CPU profiler started
Mark saved where search started [3 times]
Making python-shell-interpreter local to  *Python Internal [792caf12c778150badeeede64c068cee]* while let-bound!
Making python-shell-interpreter-args local to  *Python Internal [792caf12c778150badeeede64c068cee]* while let-bound!
Waiting for process to die...done
Quit
```

What's amazing is that after I quit the find-file with `C-g`, and re-open **the same** file with `C-x C-f` again, it loads, instantly. If, after this, I try to newly open another small python files, I have the exact same behavior - first time, emacs hangs, second time, emacs opens the file instantaneously.

None of the minor modes that are active seem threatening (I've removed all the cumbersome ones). Here are the minor modes that are activated in python mode (at least as captured when the file successfully opens the second time).

Version

```
GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9) of 2016-04-17 on lgw01-04, modified by Debian
```

Modes for buffer that's open while opening the file (same as the ones for the file that will be opened, except instead of `*scratch*`'s lisp-mode it'll be python for the `*.py`):

```
Enabled minor modes: Auto-Composition Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption
Blink-Cursor Column-Number Electric-Indent File-Name-Shadow Font-Lock
Global-Font-Lock Line-Number Menu-Bar Mouse-Wheel Shell-Dirtrack
Tool-Bar Tooltip Transient-Mark

(Information about these minor modes follows the major mode info.)

Lisp Interaction mode defined in `lisp-mode.el':
```

Comment: start turning minor modes off until you figure out what the culprit is.

Comment: @Ista do you mean start turning off minor modes that *would be started* upon opening a python file? Turning off minor modes in the current buffer (from which I open the files) does nothing.

Comment: yes, minor modes you turn on in python-mode.

Comment: @Ista I've tried it with everything that I manually enabled in my init file disabled. The ones above are automatically-added minor modes (so I can't remove any particular init line to turn them off). The issue persists. (See the post again for an update).

Comment: what happens when you start emacs with `emacs -q`?

Comment: It works, but (after restarting emacs one more time, without changing init), I can't reproduce the problem. I suppose I should delete the question then? This is extremely odd behavior (though, for what it's worth, the minor modes in the setting for emacs -q are identical to those listed in my question).

Comment: If it does happen again, try sending SIGUSR2 while it's stuck to get a backtrace.

Comment: @npostavs will do. Though won't that be equivalent to the trace from the profiler, pretty much?

Comment: Only if it's stuck in a busy loop maxing out the CPU, I think.

Comment: @npostavs awesome advice, thanks! it's doing the same error again, and I got the backtrace: https://gist.github.com/vlad17/06d453f7895322509d4f059f371625e8

Comment: Hmm, the `accept-process-output` is getting a timeout of 100ms, so it shouldn't slow things down too much. If you do it again, do you always get the same backtrace?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, the error just vanished again (I swear, I'm not changing anything) :/

At least the root cause is obvious. Next time it happens I'll just shut off ycmd

Comment: If it happens again, it might be interesting to hit `d` a few times to step forward, and see if the problem is that `accept-process-output` is getting stuck (which would be an Emacs bug), or if it's being called repeatedly (which would be a ycmd bug).

Comment: I used Jupyter notebook for practising python code. but today suddenly the py file has shot to the size of 98MB from 77 KB? now it is taking long time to open? need help how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue and dug a little more into it. Launching emacs with:

```
emacs -nw -Q
```

lets me load any python file instantly without issues (whereas `emacs -q -nw` still takes forever to load even an empty python file). I thus tried:

```
emacs -nw --no-site-file
```

and again had no issues. I then looked for the `site-start.el` file and found in `/etc/emacs/site-start.d` the file:

```
/etc/emacs/site-start.d/50pylint.el
```

removing this solved the issue. I then removed `pylint` from my system and again emacs worked correctly. Re-installing `pylint` had the issue re-appear. There is a related bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pylint/+bug/1530667). For me the issue started out of nowhere, I didn't re-install `pylint` (or anything else for that matters) and I still don't have a solution besides removing `50pylint.el`.